# Change jQuery overlay image from button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the jQuery-ui dialog overlay image with a button click from inside the dialog, but in the code below the overlay image does not change. I need to edit the CSS of the overlay dynamically in the click event.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var divCustom = '<div id="myOverlay">
                         <div id="button1">button1</div>
                         <div id="button2">button2</div>
                     </div>';

    $(divCustom).dialog({ height: 400, width: 700, modal: true });

    $("#button1").click(function(){
        $("#myOverlay .ui-widget-overlay").css({ 
            "background-image": "happy.gif"
        });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function(){
        $("#myOverlay .ui-widget-overlay").css({ 
            "background-image": "sad.gif" 
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Also, please clean up your code example's formatting.

Comment: the overlay image does not change

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What do you see when you debug with the console?

Comment: there is a syntax error on the string definition. that should be like this, `var divCustom = '<div id="myOverlay"><div id="button1">button1</div><div id="button2">button2</div></div>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot test this without JSFiddle but probably the following should help:

```
$("#myOverlay .ui-widget-overlay").css({ "background-image": "url(happy.gif)" });
```